# Where are app preferences stored in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Where in Chrome do I look to indicate which app to open a specific file type with, or which app to open when clicking a mailto link? Firefox has an entire tab devoted to this, but I can't find anything in the Chrome prefs that will let me, for example, tell Chrome to open LibreOffice instead of Excel when I click on a .xls link.

Comment: What are you using in Firefox out of interest?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome does not have it's own preferences for file type associations. Instead, it uses the defaults as managed by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's built by design to be predominately 'self contained' so everything in the cloud as such (with offline sync but still in the browser) but I have wanted to do similar and it doesn't seem there is a straight forward solution. I think @iglvzx is right but as far as settings go but as for acomplishing what you are after there are solutions, like the Firefox plugin;

[Making Gmail your default mail application](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966)

http://www.openitonline.com/

http://www.ghacks.net/2010/04/09/google-docs-windows-explorer-integration-ask-the-readers/ - This article didn't answer the question as such so I haven't quoted but some of the comments at the bottom might be useful.

Comment here with your findings =)

Comment: I'll take a look at those tonight. I use Thunderbird for mail, and it would be nice if clicking on a mailto link would actually open thunderbird and compose a new message. Seems silly to need an extension to do that. I know Chrome was trying to be an a la carte browser (i.e. only what you need) but more and more I'm thinking I'll go back to FF because of things like this.

Comment: I never adopted Firefox so I don't miss what I don't know but Chrome is blisteringly fast and there is more and more Firefox equivalent functionality. It is now taking over as the no.2 browser according to a number of sources so I would use bother for the time being